# Fast way to check azure storage account file share used capacity with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

It is too slow to check storage account file share folder number of files and capacity through Storage Explorer.
Is there a more fast way to get this information? Through powershell, for example?

Comment: Just to clarify, get the number of files(or folders) ? and the total used capacity?

Comment: Total number of files in folder and subfolders;
total used capacity: sum of space used of all files.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the code below(write in PowerShell ISE):

```
$fileinfor =@{count=0;length=0}

function file_info()
{

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName your_storage_account_name -StorageAccountKey your_storage_account_key
$shares = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $context

foreach($share in $shares)
{
#get all the files and directories in a file share
$filesAndDirs = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $share.name -Context $context

foreach($f in $filesAndDirs)
{
if($f.gettype().name -eq "CloudFile")
{
Write-Output $f.name
$fileinfor["count"]++
$fileinfor["length"]=$fileinfor["length"]+$f.Properties.Length

}
elseif($f.gettype().name -eq "CloudFileDirectory")
{
list_subdir($f)
}
}

}
Write-Output ""
Write-Output "File total count: "$fileinfor["count"]
Write-Output "File total length: "$fileinfor["length"]

}


function list_subdir([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileDirectory]$dirs)
{

$path = $dirs.Uri.PathAndQuery.Remove(0,($dirs.Uri.PathAndQuery.IndexOf('/',1)+1))
$filesAndDirs = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $dirs.share.name -Path $path -Context $context | Get-AzStorageFile
foreach($f in $filesAndDirs)
{
if($f.gettype().name -eq "CloudFile")
{
Write-Output $f.name
$fileinfor["count"]++
$fileinfor["length"]=$fileinfor["length"]+$f.Properties.Length

}
elseif($f.gettype().name -eq "CloudFileDirectory")
{
list_subdir($f)
}

}

}



file_info
```

And the test result:

[image]

Comment: @villar, if the answer works, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below powershell code should work

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <storage-account-name> -StorageAccountKey <storage-account-key>
(Get-AzureStorageShare -Context $ctx).count
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. `Get-AzureStorageShare` Cmdlet lists the shares in a storage account whereas OP is looking for a count of files & folders in a share.